# Running Python code in Vim

Tags: python, vim

I am writing Python code using Vim, and every time I want to run my code, I type this inside Vim:

```
:w !python
```

This gets frustrating, so I was looking for a quicker method to run Python code inside Vim. Executing Python scripts from a terminal maybe?
I am using Linux.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

How about adding an `autocmd` to your `~/.vimrc`-file, creating a mapping:

```
autocmd FileType python map <buffer> <F9> :w<CR>:exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
autocmd FileType python imap <buffer> <F9> <esc>:w<CR>:exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
```

then you could press `<F9>` to execute the current buffer with `python`

Explanation:

- `autocmd`: command that Vim will execute automatically on `{event}` (here: if you open a python file)
- `[i]map`: creates a keyboard shortcut to `<F9>` in insert/normal mode
- `<buffer>`: If multiple buffers/files are open: just use the active one
- `<esc>`: leaving insert mode
- `:w<CR>`: saves your file
- `!`: runs the following command in your shell (try `:!ls`)
- `%`: is replaced by the filename of your active buffer. *But* since it can contain things like whitespace and other "bad" stuff it is better practise not to write `:python %`, but use:
- `shellescape`: escape the special characters. The `1` means with a backslash

TL;DR: The first line will work in normal mode and once you press `<F9>` it first saves your file and then run the file with python.
The second does the same thing, but leaves insert mode first

Comment: @ArditSulce in your vimrc file, add a line: `autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> .... `

Comment: If you're on os x (and I assume unix) ".vimrc" is in the home directory. You can check this by typing ':version' in command mode to check for sure you'll see a line called 'user vimrc file: "..."'

Comment: Is there a way to save and run the same file, instead of just running it

Comment: @Bharat maybe this should work `nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec 'w !python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>`

Comment: `nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :!python %<cr>` seems to work in Vim 7.4.1689. What's the shellescape for?

Comment: @MatthewKleinsmith after all, your python src is a file. A file name can contain many interesting characters.

Comment: @Kent is it possible to yank something in vi and pass it to a python function. i think that i have seen this defined to add a column of numbers, but never managed to do it :(

Comment: @AlexanderCska yes, it is possible. you can read the `"` register to get the yanked text.

Comment: I noticed this command only works while the file is opened. Once I close the file and reopen it I can no longer press F9 to run the file. Is there any way to permanently allow F9 to run a Python script in Vim?

Comment: What does the `@` symbol do? I can't find an explanation for it.

Comment: @Kent I tried that, no luck: `Execute the contents of register {0-9a-z".=*+} [count] times.  Note that register '%' (name of the current file) and '#' (name of the alternate file) cannot be used.`
Not very useful, given the fact it says `%` doesn't apply.

Comment: @brainplot sorry, my bad, I didn't read it carefully. It is to get the value of a register. The doc is here: `:h expression-syntax` you may want to read `expr9`carefully.

Comment: @user117294 conversely, this only worked for me once I closed my .py file and reopened it (I think due to the <buffer> option). Did you add the autocmd to your ~/.vimrc?

Comment: An improvement would be exchanging `:w<CR>` for `:up<CR>`, because update only writes the buffer if it has changed.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I replace `'!python3'` with `'!/usr/bin/env python3'` for the reasons [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429517), and would encourage others to consider doing so too

Comment: Is there a good way to clear the terminal before executing the code?

Answer (score 75):

Just go to normal mode by pressing `<esc>` and type:

```
! clear; python %
```

[image]

> #### Step by step explanation:
>
> `!` allows you to run a terminal command
>
> `clear` will empty your terminal screen
>
> `;` ends the first command, allowing you to introduce a second command
>
> `python` will use python to run your script (it could be replaced with
>   `ruby` for example)
>
> `%` concats the current filename, passing it as a parameter to the
>   `python` command

Comment: OP is looking for an alternative to typing long command. How does this answer help him achieve that?

Answer (score 38):

I have this in my .vimrc file:

```
imap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!clear;python %<CR>
```

When I'm done editing a Python script, I just press `<F5>`. The script is saved and then executed in a blank screen.

Comment: Thank you! It works pretty well. I wonder how can I set the shortcut to `m` key plus `,` key instead of `F5` key?

Comment: Should be noted that this executes in `Insert` mode. For execution in `Normal` mode use `nmap` instead of `imap`.

Comment: Is it important not have space before and after `:w`?

Answer (score 16):

Building on the previous answers, if you like to see the code while looking at its' output you could find `:ter` (`:terminal`) command useful.

```
autocmd Filetype python nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<CR>:ter python2 "%"<CR>
autocmd Filetype python nnoremap <buffer> <F6> :w<CR>:vert ter python3 "%"<CR>
```

Using `vert` in the second line runs the code in vertical split instead of horizontal.

The negative of it is that if you don't close the split-window where the code ran you will have many splits after multiple runs (which doesn't happen in original python IDLE where the same output window is reused).

(I keep these lines inside `/home/user/.vimrc`)

Comment: Beginner follow up question: How do you return to the file you were editing after using this command?

Comment: Ctrl+w, then direction key (e.g. h,j,k,l). Or ":q" to close the output.

Answer (score 10):

Plugin: [jupyter-vim](https://github.com/jupyter-vim/jupyter-vim)

So you can send lines (`<leader>E`), visual selection (`<leader>e`) to a running `jupyter-client` (the replacement of `ipython`)

[image]

I prefer to separate editor and interpreter (each one in its shell). Imagine you send a bad input reading command ...

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that you're able to repeat the last used command with `@:`, so that's all you'd need to repeat are those two character.

Or you could save the string `w !python` into one of the registers (like `"a` for example) and then hit `:<C-R>a<CR>` to insert the contents of register `a` into the commandline and run it.

Or you can do what I do and map `<leader>z` to `:!python %<CR>` to run the current file.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to see "`:exec python file.py`" printed each time, use this:

```
nnoremap <F9> :echo system('python2 "' . expand('%') . '"')<cr>
nnoremap <F10> :echo system('python3 "' . expand('%') . '"')<cr>
```

It didn't mess up my powerline / vim-airline statusbar either.

Answer (score 5):

Think about using shebang line, so you will be able to use it with still any language, not only Python.

**Adding shebang:**

Add this to first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

or this, if you are using Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

**Vim keymap:**

Add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap <F7> :w<cr>:!clear;"%:p"<cr>
```

**Make file executable:**

Type in Vim:

```
:!chmod +x %
```

or in terminal:

```
chmod +x script_name.py
```

**Explanation:**

When F7 is pressed in normal mode, Vim will try to execute current file as bash script. Then bash interpreter will see shebang line and understand, that this file should be passed to Python (or any other programm if needed).

Also you will be able to run your script from terminal using it's name:

```
./script_name.py
```

instead of this way (that will work too):

```
python3 script_name.py
```

Comment: I was thinking for a way to extend FucusedWolf answer to use the same time for both python2 and 3 versions, since I had to. Then yet again, this in combine with that would do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For generic use (run python/haskell/ruby/C++... from vim based on the `filetype`), there's a nice plugin called [vim-quickrun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun). It supports many programming languages by default. It is easily configurable, too, so one can define preferred behaviours for any filetype if needed. The github repo does not have a fancy readme, but it is well documented with the doc file.

Answer (score 3):

I have this on my .vimrc:

```
"map <F9> :w<CR>:!python %<CR>"
```

which saves the current buffer and execute the code with presing only Esc + F9

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works for me (on Linux), but I wanted this command to also save the buffer before running, so I modified it slightly:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :w <bar> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

The `:w <bar>` saves the buffer THEN runs the code in it.

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
:! [filename.py]; python %
```

That's what works for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use [skywind3000/asyncrun.vim](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) as well. It is similar to what @FocusedWolf has listed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your home directory. `cd`
2. Open your .vimrc file with vim. `vim .vimrc`
3. Add the next code to the file. `nmap <F4> <Esc>:w<CR>:!clear;python %<CR>`
4. Save it and quit. `ZZ`

The next time you want to run your code, just press `F4` in "normal mode". If you want to run your code in "insert mode", replace `nmap` with `imap`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use Vim-Slime plugin for "by-block" sending python code from vim to python console.

https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime

Answer (score 2):

I use this. It automatically saves the program and runs it into the shell. Comes back to vim after the program is run.

Works by pressing `<F5>` in insert mode in vim.
Add the following code snippet in your vimrc file.

```
imap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!python % [filename.py]; <CR>
```

I have just combined the two solutions previously provided to this question and it worked for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple method would be to type `:` while in normal mode, and then press the up arrow key on the keyboard and press Enter. This will repeat the last typed commands on VIM.

Comment: You can do an incremental search by typing the starting characters of the command before pressing the up arrow. If many commands ago I did a ! python %, I could :! then press the up arrow, to only cycle through commands that start with !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quickly jump back through your `:w` commands, a cool thing is to type `:w` and then press your up arrow. It will only cycle through commands that start with `w`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor in the code somewhere. Right click and choose one of the "Select" choices to highlight your code. Then press Ctrl : and you will see the new prompt '<, >'

Now type !python and see if that works.

I just spend days trying to figure out the same problem!!! I used the coding:

```
s='My name'
print (s)
```

After I pulled out all my hair, I finally got it right!

Comment: Using mouse in not a vim way

Comment: But it's possible to do `:% !python`. `%` just means all lines.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the command mapping in your `.vimrc`, put the mapping in your `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` file (Windows `$HOME\vimfiles\ftplugin\python.vim`).  If you don't have this file or directories, just make them.  This way the key is only mapped when you open a `.py` file or any file with `filetype=python`, since you'll only be running this command on Python scripts.

For the actual mapping, I like to be able to edit in Vim while the script runs.  Going off of @cazyas' answer, I have the following in my `ftplugin\python.vim` (Windows):

```
noremap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!START /B python %<CR>
```

This will run the current Python script in the background.  For Linux just change it to this:

```
noremap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!python % &<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extends for any language with 1 keybinding with augroup command, for example:

```
augroup rungroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.go nnoremap <F5> :exec '!go run' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py nnoremap <F5> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using:

```
:!python nameofyourfile.py
```

example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjUxEX4OssM

It could just be your syntax, or it could be that you are missing pluggin or packages others have used. Are you using just plain terminal, or something else like MobaXterm?
The above code works for running a python script using terminal inside vim (the output will show up inside the vim session).

Answer (score 1):

`:!./%` run the current Python script, this will work only with the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

You can also run it with arguments like that:

`:!./% ARG1 ARG2`

Answer (score 0):

This .vimrc mapping needs [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771), but it replicates Geany (and other X editors') behaviour:

- Press a key to execute
- Executes in gnome-terminal
- Waits for confirmation to exit
- Window closes automatically on exit

  `:let dummy = conque_term#subprocess('gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"python ' . expand("%") . '; answer=\\\"z\\\"; while [  $answer != \\\"q\\\" ]; do printf \\\"\nexited with code $?, press (q) to quit: \\\";  read -n 1 answer; done; \" "')`

Answer (score 0):

```
" run current python file to new buffer
function! RunPython()
    let s:current_file = expand("%")
    enew|silent execute ".!python " . shellescape(s:current_file, 1)
    setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile nowrap
    setlocal nobuflisted
endfunction
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <Leader>c :call RunPython()<CR>
```

Comment: This script runs the code replacing the buffer where the code is written.