# How to run go lang code directly from vim?

Tags: vim, go

How to run `go lang` `code` directly from `vim editor` ?

e.g. currently edited file is `array.go`.
What kind of commands should I use to run this code in vim?

Comment: Using `:!` for instance?

Comment: go is not a scripting language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok so after some trials this works: `!go run %`

Comment: `au FileType go map <leader>r :!go run %<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you've set environment variables properly; you can use this `_gvimrc` file (on Windows, it should be at `C:\Users\UserName`; on Linux, I do not know):

```
set guifont=Lucida_Console:h11
colorscheme dejavu
set tabstop=4

filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

" causes vim opens maximized in windows (@least)
au GUIEnter * simalt ~x

set autochdir
set number
set nobackup
" set nowritebackup

" this made my vim life (as a begginer at least) much happier!
" thanks to @ http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window bottom of the page
function! s:ExecuteInShell(command, bang)
    let _ = a:bang != '' ? s:_ : a:command == '' ? '' : join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))

    if (_ != '')
        let s:_ = _
        let bufnr = bufnr('%')
        let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . _ . '$')
        silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'belowright new ' . fnameescape(_) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
        setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile wrap number
        silent! :%d
        let message = 'Execute ' . _ . '...'
        call append(0, message)
        echo message
        silent! 2d | resize 1 | redraw
        silent! execute 'silent! %!'. _
        silent! execute 'resize ' . line('$')
        silent! execute 'syntax on'
        silent! execute 'autocmd BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr . ') . ''wincmd w'''
        silent! execute 'autocmd BufEnter <buffer> execute ''resize '' .  line(''$'')'
        silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <CR> :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . _ . ''', '''')<CR>'
        silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . _ . ''', '''')<CR>'
        silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>g :execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr . ') . ''wincmd w''<CR>'
        nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <C-W>_ :execute 'resize ' . line('$')<CR>
        silent! syntax on
    endif
endfunction

command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=* -bang Shell call s:ExecuteInShell(<q-args>, '<bang>')
cabbrev shell Shell

" my additional tools
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=* -bang Gor call s:ExecuteInShell('go run %', '<bang>')
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=* -bang Gon call s:ExecuteInShell('go install', '<bang>')
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=* -bang Gob call s:ExecuteInShell('go build', '<bang>')
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=* -bang Got call s:ExecuteInShell('go test -v', '<bang>')

:map <F5>  :Gor<CR>
:map <F6>  :Gob<CR>
:map <F7>  :Gon<CR>
:map <F9>  :Got<CR>
:map <F10> :Fmt<CR>:w<CR>
:map <F12> :q<CR>

cabbrev fmt Fmt

:set encoding=utf-8
:set fileencodings=utf-8
```

Now when you press `F5` it will run go (`go run file.go`) and shows the output in another document (you can `:q` to close the other document). Other commands are: `F6` build, `F7` install, `F9` test and (my beloved one) `F10` is `fmt`+`:w`.

BTW `dejavu` is my favorite color-scheme (code is from gorilla/mux):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also map a key in your `~/.vimrc` as this

```
nnoremap gr :!go run %<CR>
```

So you can easily type `gr` in your vim and it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

add the following two lines to your vimrc.

`autocmd FileType go map <buffer> <F9> :w<CR>:exec '!go run' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>`

`autocmd FileType go imap <buffer> <F9> <esc>:w<CR>:exec '!go run' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>`

this is inspired by [an answer to a similar python question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18948530/11403193)