# Vim and Python configuration

Tags: python, vim

I want to compile and run a Python script using Gvim.

I have configured this in my `_vimrc`:

```
map <F5>:!D:\Python27\python.exe%
```

But when I complete the Python code and then enter <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, I receive the error:

> E448 Extra tail characters

How can I solve this?

Comment: You may find the [SingleCompile plug-in](http://www.topbug.net/SingleCompile/) useful, rather than write your own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948491/running-python-code-in-vim/18948530#18948530

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you do **not** normally compile python - you just **run** it.

Second I suspect that you need a space before the % in your configuration assuming that it gets replaced by the filename.

Comment: Well, when you run a python script it **is** *compiled* to bytecode first. In fact there exist a `compile` built-in that performs this step while `eval`/`exec` first compile the code and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing spaces, in two important areas:

- First, there must be whitespace separating the `{lhs}` (`<F5>` in your case) from the `{rhs}` (to what the mapping is expanded.
- Second, the `%` that Vim will expand to the filename must be separated from the Python executable path, or else you'll end up with something like `python.exeFoo.py`, which the operating system doesn't understand.

Additionally:

- You should select the proper modes for your mapping; these usually aren't invoked by <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (for which you would need `:cmap`, and omit the `:`), but rather by just pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> from *normal mode* (`:nmap`).
- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

```
:nnoremap <F5> :!D:\Python27\python.exe %<CR>
```