# how to map a key for all opened buffers in vim while programming python

Tags: python, vim, dictionary

I found this link for mapping a key for running python code in vim; however, when I open a second or third buffer the key doesn't work. How could I make the mapping permanent for all open buffers.
[Running Python code in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948491/running-python-code-in-vim)

thanks

Comment: What mapping are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What mapping are you talking about?

The mapping in [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18948530/546861) is pretty good. Add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` to activate it every Python buffer:

```
augroup Python
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mapping contains `<buffer>` it means it creates the mapping for the buffer.

Remove `<buffer>` from the mapping.