# When running python from vim, how to move through the output window

Tags: python, vim

It is explained in many places, how to run a python script from vim including [Running Python code in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948491/running-python-code-in-vim).

But my output spans across pages and only I can see the last page. I am not able to move to top of the results.

I tried :!clear;python % | more. This will keep the output in more, but once more is exited, things are same. Any ways to move in the result pane?

Also I not able to add the shortcut "map  :w:!python %|more".

Comment: try reading this http://askubuntu.com/questions/273066/running-python-in-vim

Comment: @PetarP: %pyf is very much similar to  ;python % | more. It also does not accept raw_input. Giving an error "    count = raw_input('Enter Count -')
EOF \n Error: EOF when reading a line "

Comment: Here is a official vim documents, this first part should handle your error, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Execute_Python_from_within_current_file

Comment: I would use `:new` followed by `:r !command`, but I'm sure there's a way to avoid the `:new` if you know what you're doing (I don't).

Comment: Just run your code in another shell.

Comment: I found a better way to run the python from the vim. This will display the output into a new window, where you can use vim commands to search, replace and so on. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window

Answer (score 0):

The output is simply printed out into your terminal, so you should use terminal's capabilities to scroll. Both Linux TTY and many X11 terminal emulators support <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd>; in X11, you can also use scrolling wheel if that's your thing.

If you need to process the output using Vim, you should prefix your `!` with `read`: `:read !python %`; that will put the output into the current buffer.

> Also I not able to add the shortcut "map :w:!python %|more".

It's better to ask only one question per post. What you're missing in your command is the key you're binding the command to; you should also escape `%` and `|`.