# R: Terminal IDE for Centos6 server without admin access

Tags: r, vim, ide

I need a replacement for RStudio Server which I can install and manage myself on a remote server (no `sudo` access). Gedit + XQuartz on my MacBook performs very poorly due to the lack of integration with R.

I was looking at [vimR](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r/vim-r), and it appears to have the functionality that I need and should be able to easily extend to Python and other programming languages, which is important. But I think this guide is out of date, and the installation of dependencies is convoluted and ultimately requires installing via the package manager which is not an option.

Are there other alternatives to this? Google has not brought up anything useful so far.

Comment: If you work most of the time in shell you'll hardly find Sublime useful - so different flavors of vim, including vimr, and vundle to customize for specific languages would be probably the best choice https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I have Sublime already as well. What I need is the ability to write my script in a text-editor and also run it line by line, the way you can in Rstudio for R or Rodeo for Python. Are vim based approaches able to accomplish that? I can't tell from the descriptions. Being forced to run the entire script every time is not feasible when loading each dataset can take upwards of 30 seconds. And I can't stand having to tweak each line on the R terminal then copy the final version back to the script over & over

Comment: There's a number of ways to customize .vimrc and allow running scripts like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948491/running-python-code-in-vim

Comment: @dmitryro All those are basically variations of `:!python %`.  What you want these days is [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) (formerly IPython).  The integration with Vim is [less then great](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython), but Jupyter itself is outstanding, and it does have [Vim key bindings](https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding).  And you'll still find uses for `vim-r`.

Comment: Yes I have Jupyter installed on the remote server but the server does not have http access and I have not been able to get my local Jupyter notebooks to connect to the remote iPython kernels, or otherwise access the remote Jupyter in any fashion besides a QT terminal. Its very likely that I don't have it configured correctly but I have not found a guide that worked yet. I prefer Rodeo over Jupyer notebook as an IDE and was hoping to eventually have it connected to the remote Jupyter instance but so far no luck.

Comment: and `vim-r` was just a suggestion, I am willing to use whatever tool offers this functionality though I would especially appreciate one that is expandable to multiple languages easily, saw [emacs](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/using-emacs-to-work-with-r/) implementations but wasn't clear if the same implementations worked with Python as well. A common vim issue I keep hitting is that my CentOS 6 has vim 7.2 while most plugins now want 7.4