# Difference between :pyf % and :!python % for running python code

Tags: python, vim

I use to map <kbd>F9</kbd> to `:pyf %` to run python files from `vim`. But after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948491/running-python-code-in-vim), which suggests

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

Just wondering which approach should be preferred for running python code from `vim` session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:pyfile` is a variant of `:python` (that reads the code from a file, not as direct arguments). Both execute the code **inside Vim's embedded Python interpreter**. This is mostly meant for Vim plugins written in Python. You have access to Vim's Python interface (cp. `:help python-vim`), and any code / globals will persist until you quit Vim.

*For trivial code without side effects, this should be fine, although it's not meant for that.*

---

`:!python ...` launches an **external Python interpreter**, completely separate from Vim. Vim doesn't even need to be compiled with Python support here. As each invocation is a separate process, there's no persistence between runs. Each one is fresh, just like launching the script directly from the command-line. Also, you're using the system's default Python interpreter, not the one Vim was compiled against.

*I would recommend this approach, unless you're explicitly writing a Vim plugin.*

Comment: Thanks, Ingo, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

`:pythonfile` executes the file with Python built-in into vim so the script can import module `vim`.

`!python` executes external interpreter that doesn't have any access to vim internals.